# Character Limit on Field Sizes

Tags: fields

In most database field constraints, you can put a top limit on the number of characters allowed in that field. I looked up whether there is such a setting in SalesForce and the search results were more about the gap between data types, than there being a specific constraint.

Is there a way to limit a text field to a small number of characters? For example, could we limit the Salutation list to 5 chars per option?

Comment: when you create a field (text field for example) you are given the option to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom fields can be explicitly configured, but standard fields can not. Salutation, for example, is a standard picklist, so you cannot customize the maximum length.